# Multithreading programing in Win32

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, deadlock

I use mutex to sync file writing and reading. I create some threads to read file and some threads to write file. But writing Thread sometimes block in   WaitForSingleObject(hMutexRW,INFINITE). I'm new to Win32 Threads programming and I don't know what the problem is. I think the mutex is the problem, and I want to know how to solve this problem.

```
const int nThreadWriting = 5;
const int nThreadReading = 5;
const int nBufSize = 100;
const int maxWritten = 10;
const int timeRange = 3;
HANDLE hMutexRW, hMutexW, hMutexR, hMutexN;
int currentSemaphoreR = 0;
int numberWritten = 0;

unsigned __stdcall ThreadReading(void *pV)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    int waitTime, lastTime;
    char buf[nBufSize];
    int* ptr = (int*)pV;
    srand(*ptr);
    while (1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexN, INFINITE);
        if (numberWritten >= maxWritten)
        {
            ReleaseMutex(hMutexN);
            return 0;
        }
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexN);

        waitTime = rand() % timeRange+1;
        lastTime = rand() % timeRange+1;

        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexW, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexR, INFINITE);
        if (currentSemaphoreR == 0)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(hMutexRW, INFINITE);
            sprintf_s(buf, nBufSize, "%d R GET MUTEX_RW\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
            std::cout << buf << std::endl;
        }
        currentSemaphoreR++;
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexR);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexW);

        hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("nice.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            std::cout << "cannot open file" << std::endl;
        }
        sprintf_s(buf, nBufSize, "%d R %d %d\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), waitTime, lastTime);
        std::cout << buf <<std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexR, INFINITE);
        currentSemaphoreR--;
        if (currentSemaphoreR == 0)
            ReleaseMutex(hMutexRW);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexR);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall ThreadWriting(void *pV)
{
    int waitTime, lastTime;
    char buf[nBufSize];
    int* ptr = (int*)pV;
    srand(*ptr);
    HANDLE hFile;
    while (1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexN, INFINITE);
        if (numberWritten >= maxWritten)
        {
            ReleaseMutex(hMutexN);
            return 0;
        }
        numberWritten++;
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexN);
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexW, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexRW, INFINITE);
        hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("nice.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            std::cout << "cannot open file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_END);
        sprintf_s(buf, nBufSize, "%d W %d %d\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), waitTime, lastTime);
        WriteFile(hFile, buf, strlen(buf), NULL, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexRW);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexW);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("nice.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    DWORD IDThread[nThreadWriting+ nThreadReading];
    HANDLE hThread[nThreadWriting + nThreadReading];
    int num[nThreadWriting + nThreadReading];
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreadWriting + nThreadReading; i++)
        num[i] = i;
    hMutexRW = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    hMutexR = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    hMutexW = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    hMutexN = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!hMutexRW || !hMutexW || !hMutexR)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreadReading; i++)
    {
        hThread[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadReading, num + i, 0, (unsigned int*)&IDThread[i]);
        if (!hThread[i])
            ExitProcess(3);
    }
    for (int i = nThreadReading; i < nThreadWriting + nThreadReading; i++)
    {
        hThread[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadWriting, num + i, 0, (unsigned int*)&IDThread[i]);
        if (!hThread[i])
            ExitProcess(3);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreadWriting + nThreadReading, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreadWriting + nThreadReading; i++)
        CloseHandle(hThread[i]);
    CloseHandle(hMutexRW);
    CloseHandle(hMutexR);
    CloseHandle(hMutexW);
    CloseHandle(hMutexN);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Careful with `srand` and `rand`. They are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: You have more mutexs in there than I would be comfortable with. I haven't looked very closely, but you'll have to be very careful that you don't wind up in a deadlock with one thread holding mutex A while locked waiting on B with another thread holding B mutex while waiting on A or similar nastiness.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I find the problem! It's because Mutex should be released within the thread which had own the Mutex, so I use Semaphore instead. And thank for you remind that the ```rand``` is an thread unsafe function though I have little idea about what result it can lead...

Comment: One possibility is `rand` may advance to next number in the generator's sequence, then return the value. If two threads get in at the same time you could wind up with thread 1 advances sequence, thread2 advances sequence, thread 1 returns value, thread 2 returns value. Thread 1 and 2 returned the same value. If the advancing of the sequence is complicated enough and is interrupted by another thread part way through, Crom only knows what will happen.

Comment: Mind you `rand` could be really simple and [always return 4](https://xkcd.com/221/). It's a pretty weakly specified function.

Comment: remove semaphores. you can use file handles in `WaitForSingleObject`